# How can I call an Array into another function with a return value?

Tags: c, arrays

So, I'm trying to recall an array generated in one function into another function to work with it. Now, I've looked around and I can see that you can't call an entire array, but can call its pointer. I am not entirely sure how to do this and my attempts have led me to failure.

So I come to you, here is what my code looks like so far (or at least the two functions I am currently trying to work with):

```
int CreatePermutation(int n){
    int arr[25];

    printf ("Please enter desired permutation size: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    while(n<=0){
        printf ("Please input a possitive number for a permutation size.\n");
        printf ("Please enter desired permutation size: ");
        scanf ("%d", &n);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        arr [i] = i+1;

    return arr[25];

}

int main (){
    int arr[25];
    int n;

    CreatePermutation(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d", arr[i]);


}
```

When I tried the CreatePermutation as a main function to see if it worked, it was generating and printing the permutations correctly, so all I really need is a way to get it into the main function.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the array as an argument:

```
int CreatePermutation(int *arr){       
    int n;

    printf ("Please enter desired permutation size: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    while(n<=0){
        printf ("Please input a possitive number for a permutation size.\n");
        printf ("Please enter desired permutation size: ");
        scanf ("%d", &n);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        arr [i] = i+1;  

    return n;    
}

int main (){
    int arr[25];  
    int n;      

    n = CreatePermutation(arr);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d", arr[i]); 

    return 0;
}
```

This way, you can modify the array using the array pointer.  You can also return the size of the permutation in your `CreatePermutation` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
int CreatePermutation(int n, int* arr)
{


printf ("Please enter desired permutation size: ");
scanf ("%d", &n);

while(n<=0){
    printf ("Please input a possitive number for a permutation size.\n");
    printf ("Please enter desired permutation size: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
}

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    arr [i] = i+1;

return arr[n-1];

}

int main (){
int arr[25];
int n = 25;  /* Update thanks to PHIFounder */

CreatePermutation(n, arr);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%d", arr[i]);


}
```

Comment: Well, it seems to work, but after running it like this, it generates the code and does print it but it also prints a bunch of additional, unwanted info. 
As in, when I make n = 7, it'll print out 1234567 which is correct, but that is followed by a bunch of random digits. how do i make it stop at the end of my array?

Comment: @AllanRansomSoto Run another loop in createPermutation function till the number `n` and append `'\0'` after the loop and then return the array or return `arr[n];`

Comment: When you call the function in main it uses `n` which is uninitialized which eventually results in garbage

Comment: @AllanRansomSoto Use a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

I will show simple example to make things clearer , you can get a clue from it and apply in your problem .

If you want then you can do it like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int CreatePermutation(int arr[] , int n)
{
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr [i] = i+1;

  return arr[n-1]; 

}

int main ()
{
  int arr[25];
  int n ;

  printf ("Please enter number of elements to be printed : ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);//You should enter the number of elements before passing it to the function and in this way you can limit the number of elements you want to print .

  CreatePermutation ( arr , n );

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("%d\n" , arr[i] );


}
```

**NOTE--** My example shows a simple way to pass array as per your intention , you can further adjust it according to your needs :)